# Spark large deserialization time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark and I seem to have some performance issues. I'm trying to calculate simple calculation between different parameters in my DataFrame (I'm using PySpark on Spark 1.5.2 to do that), but the problem is that my task deserialization time is huge comparing to the actual calculation.

Here are screenshots when calculating calculation between two different pairs of parameters.

[image: time 1]

[image: time 2]

To calculate correlations I'm just using `full_dataframe.stat.corr('param1', 'param2')`. The dataset has been cached first and then this calculation is performed. I'm actually trying to calculate correlation between all parameters and produce a correlation map, so I'm calling this line in a loop where I iterate through different combinations of parameters. Size of cached dataset is 5.2GB.

I'm running this job on a 4 cluster machine (YARN) where each machine has:

- 10GB RAM (8GB reserved for YARN)
- 8 cores (16 virtual cores, 14 reserved for YARN)

I'm using PySpark through Jupyter and I've started it using:

pyspark --master yarn --driver-memory 2560m --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 5G --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048

I've tried with different number of partitions using `df.repartition(no_of_partitions)`, such as 16, 32, 128, 256, but nothing helps.

Additionally, after a while my job breaks completely and I get the following error from the ui:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /proxy/application_1485432889177_0016/stages/stage. Reason:

    Connection to http://192.168.84.27:4040 refused
Caused by:

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.84.27:4040 refused
```

And when I look at the output of my Jupyter I see these exceptions:

```
17/01/29 17:06:06 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread task-result-getter-14
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.trim(ByteVectorImpl.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:386)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-13" 17/01/29 17:06:06 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread task-result-getter-15
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.trim(ByteVectorImpl.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:386)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.trim(ByteVectorImpl.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:386)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-12" Exception in thread "task-result-getter-14" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.trim(ByteVectorImpl.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:386)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
```

What could be the cause of such behavior and how to solve it?

---

After changing the min and max split size I got a similar GC error in the driver:

```
    17/01/29 21:37:43 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.resize(ByteVectorImpl.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.add(ByteVectorImpl.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitByte(ClassFileAssembler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitShort(ClassFileAssembler.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitConstantPoolNameAndType(ClassFileAssembler.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:313)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
17/01/29 21:37:46 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.resize(ByteVectorImpl.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.add(ByteVectorImpl.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitByte(ClassFileAssembler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitShort(ClassFileAssembler.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitConstantPoolNameAndType(ClassFileAssembler.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:313)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
17/01/29 21:37:50 ERROR ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.resize(ByteVectorImpl.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.ByteVectorImpl.add(ByteVectorImpl.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitByte(ClassFileAssembler.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitShort(ClassFileAssembler.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitConstantPoolNameAndType(ClassFileAssembler.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:313)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:340)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$writeObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:50 WARN YarnHistoryService: Discarding event
17/01/29 21:37:54 ERROR ErrorMonitor: Uncaught fatal error from thread [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] shutting down ActorSystem [sparkDriver]
```

And on the ui:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /jobs/. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
```